# Unknown column of temporary table in field list

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a temporary table that I have created to exactly match an existing table.

```
create temporary table all_plants_temp SELECT * from all_plants;
```

My goal is to have any changes made to the temporary table all_plants_temp transfer to the original table when needed. To do this, I have been trying to update the original table and set its columns equal to those of the temporary table.

```
update all_plants set all_plants.symbol = all_plants_temp.symbol...(followed by the other columns)...;
```

Doing this is giving me the following error:

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'all_plants_temp.symbol' in 'field list'
```

I've tried a number of unsuccessful variations of this code. Because I'm still a novice, I think that I may have a conceptual misunderstanding, but despite searching all over, I can't seem to find my mistake. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that the following query works

```
select symbol from all_plants_temp;
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you created the temp table correctly.  You should have used `CREATE TABLE all_plants_temp LIKE all_plants` then `INSERT all_plants_temp SELECT * FROM all_plants`

Comment: have you set proper condition in 'where' clause??? maybe there is more than one matching records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by DROP and CREATE table again something as bellow:

```
drop table all_plants;

create table all_plants SELECT * from all_plants_temp;
```

Comment: this is not a good solution when you have huge number of records in the table and few of them has been changed since the last update

Comment: Thank you! This works wonderfully, and much more quickly than I expected. Do have any idea why my original code is flawed?

Comment: @squared happy to know that it helps you. You could upvote this answer and accept it by clicking tic. How ever I'm not sure why your old one not working. I guess something problem in your syntax.

Comment: I don't have the ability to upvote yet, unfortunately.

Comment: @squared I think you could! your reputation is more than 15; i.e. 18! by the way thanks for aCCEPT

Comment: but this isn't temporary table.